.NET 8 >4s delay between OnActionExecuted and View beginning to render
I know there are a lot of moving parts to consider here but I thought I'd post and see if anyone had any thoughts.  I am running into an issue with the load time of my View being slow.  I added logging at various points within the controller and the controller code executes in around 12ms.  So I added logging at the top of my View.  There is consistently a 4-6 second delay from the time my controller code completes to the time the view begins to load:
OnActionExecuted - 7/23/2024 3:17:08 PM <- Last entry from end of ActionResult method.
RenderBegin - 7/23/2024 3:17:14 PM      <- At the top of _Layout
This is the code from Program.cs:
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

    // Get the scopes from the configuration (appsettings.json)
    var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)

.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<PreserveStateFilter>();
    builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
           .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
   .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
   .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
   .UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString));
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddRazorOptions(opt => {
        opt.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Forms/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        opt.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/ArchivedForms/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });

    builder.Services.AddSession(options => {});
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();
    

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();


    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(app.Configuration)
         .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
             connectionString: connectionString,
             sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
             {
                 TableName = "Log",
                 AutoCreateSqlTable = true
             })
         .CreateLogger();        

    // Add configuration to helper functions to allow access to app settings
    BaseModel.AppSettingsConfigure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
    FormsPortal.AppSettingsConfigure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
    HelperFunctions.AppSettingsConfigure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
    EmailUtility.AppSettingsConfigure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
    FormsJob.AppSettingsConfigure(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Equals("/hangfire", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await context.ChallengeAsync();
            return;
        }

        await next();
    });
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
    {
        AppPath = "/Forms",
        Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() },
        IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true

    });

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{encryptedId?}");
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.StartRecurringJobs();
    app.Run();


Does this delay happen in local test enviroment?

So long story short, the delay was caused by asp-for tags that were applied to my inputs.  The project generates forms and stores the form/data in JSON (so form versioning can be done and the data still matches up with the questions at that time).  Because of this, a lot of the information used to generate the form is stored in hidden fields and posted back with the form.  We started noticing the issue on some of the longer forms.
The bigger the form, the more asp-for tags that were used to generate and thus causing the delay in load.  Changing the code to iterate through and using the indexes to name the hidden fields fixed the long delay on load.  The long form in particular went from a 5s load to < 500ms.
